# How to import Actual Work to MS Project 2013 from CSV

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I would like to import CSV file with the following structure to MS Project 2013 as Tasks (type of data you want to import in the Import Wizard).

```
Outline_Level;Name;Actual_Work
1;Project name;
2;Task 1;10
2;Task 2;20
2;Task 3;30
```

Projects and tasks are imported just fine (outline works as well), but I can't import **Actual work**. Since I haven't had experience with MS Project before I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

When I add new column (since it's not displayed by default) **Actual work** it just shows 0 hrs.

I've done some research and it seems that there's some kind of VBA involved. I would appriciate any help you may provide to get me to import **Actual work**.

Thanks!

Comment: I have never imported from Excel into MS-Project, but I am not certain Project would accept values for Actuals when there are no values for Work. You could try adding values for the Work Column (and possibly the Outstanding Work column) as well as the Actual Work column, making sure the data complies with Actual+Outstanding=Work because if it doesn't then Project may well reject that too...

Comment: You can copy paste data from excel to MS Project (MPP), just open your CSV in Excel format and copy data from it and paste it to the MPP. Paste your actual work column in the Duration column in the second go. I think this should work for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should use import map in import wizard to achieve this. For more details you can refer to the following article

6 Practical Scenarios Where Excel Import is Useful - http://www.mpug.com/articles/6-practical-scenarios-where-excel-import-is-useful/

You will also find some other useful techniques of importing in this article.

Answer (score 1):

Project doesn't know what measure you are using for the actual work.  Try the import with 10h in the actual work field.  Also, generally the project name is in line zero - or the Project Summary Task.  If you name the CSV the project name and then turn on the Project Summary task, I think you'll have a correct outline.  That means that tasks 1, 2, and 3 would be outline level 1.

I hope this helps.